# Предикатив или краткое прилагательное?

Tags: предикатив

В предложении "Все будет ясно" слово "ясно" - краткое прилагательное или наречие?
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Если точнее, то это предикатив.

Разве это так?

Ведь по определению Предикативы (категория состояния, безлично-предикативные слова, предикативные слова, предикативные наречия) - слова, обозначающие нединамическое состояние и выступающие в функции главного члена (сказуемого, предиката) однокомпонентного (односоставного, безличного) предложения.

Но приведенное предложение - двусоставное. Все - подлежащее, будет ясно - сказуемое. Именная часть выражена кратким прилагательным.

Если бы было предложение: *Будет ясно* тогда *ясно* было бы предикативом.

[ГОТОВИМСЯ К ЭКЗАМЕНАМ Как различать грамматические омонимы](http://rus.1september.ru/view_article.php?ID=200901604:)

В предложении Солнце ясно светило нам в глаза выделенное слово – наречие, так как этот член предложения зависит от глагола-сказуемого, отвечает на вопрос обстоятельства: светило (как?), не изменяется. Если же неизвестная словоформа является сказуемым в безличном предложении, это слово категории состояния: Ясно было, что раненый не мог жить и что последний час его был уже близок.

Я так понимаю, что в двусоставном предложении слово не может быть предикативом.

Значение слова будет ясно. Значение - подлежащее, будет (каково?) ясно - сказуемое.

Все будет ясно. Все - подлежащее, будет (каково?) ясно - сказуемое. Это не безличное, а двусоставное предложение.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

2. К предикативам относятся слова разных частей речи, причём не во всех своих лексических значениях, а только в тех из них, которые закреплены за употреблением этих слов в функции сказуемого. Из наречий к предикатам относят: 1) слова на *-о*, соотносительные по значению с качественными наречиями, обозначающие чувство, эмоциональное или физическое состояние, например: *весело, грустно, радостно, душно, плохо* и т. д.; 2) слова, не соотносительные с качественными наречиями, обозначающие внутреннее состояние, например: *совестно, стыдно, тошно* и т. д.; 3) слова с модальными значениями должествования,необходимости, возможности, не соотносительные с качественными наречиями, обычно называемые модальными предикативами, например: *должно, можно, возможно, надо, нельзя, нужно, необходимо, надобно*.

Я что-то не пойму: Грамота объясняет, какие слова относятся к предикативам, а примеры приводятся предикатов.

Словарь лингвистических терминов

именная часть составного сказуемого

ТолкованиеПеревод
именная часть составного сказуемого
(присвязочный член, предикативный член). Та часть, которая выражает основное значение составного сказуемого. В этой функции выступает любая из именных частей речи в разных падежных формах, причастие, определительно-качественное наречие, междометие с оценочным значением, синтаксически неразложимое сочетание, фразеологический оборот. Лизавета Ивановна была домашнею мученицей (Пушкин). Ярмарка была отличнейшая (Гоголь). Степан Андреевич был умыт и расчесан и собирался одеваться (Л. Толстой). Как некстати было это воспоминание! (Чехов). Она теперь ай-ай-ай (Лесков). Лаврецкому такое множество народу было не по нутру (Тургенев). Отнесение сказуемых, в которых именная часть выражена причастием, наречием, междометием, к числу именных является условным (так как налицо нет “имени”) и основано на близости в данном случае функции этих частей речи к функции имен в роли сказуемого.

Здесь говорится: предикативный член.

Может быть, предикативный член и предикатив - это разные понятия?

Ярмарка была отличнейшая. Разве *отличнейшая* - это предикатив?

Дело, видно, вот в чем:

В русском языке предикативы можно разделить на две группы: личные и безличные.
Примеры личных форм предикативов:
Он явился раздетым (явился — это глагольная часть; раздетым — именная, предикатив).
Пейзаж красив (глагольная связка опущена, красив — именная часть).
Я стал врачом (стал — глагольная часть; врачом — именная).
Его выбрали президентом (выбрали — глагольная часть; президентом — именная).
Безлично-предикативные слова (слова состояния) употребляются в безличных предложениях. В русском языке следующие части речи могут служить безличными предикативами:
предикативные наречия (напр., темно, тесно, плохо)
страдательные причастия на -но, -то (напр., накурено, заперто),
существительные — время (Время ехать; Не время спорить), грех (Грех смеяться над несчастьем ближнего), досуг, недосуг (Недосуг мне по театрам ходить), лень (Лень заниматься музыкой), охота, неохота (Охота поговорить; Неохота с детьми возиться), пора (Пора идти домой), жаль.

Надо, оказывается, оговаривать, какой это предикатив - личный или безличный.

Все будет ясно. - Здесь *ясно* - личный предикатив.

Будет ясно. Здесь *ясно* - безличный предикатив.

предикативный член - то же, что именная часть составного сказуемого.

[Предикатив](http://russkiyyazik.ru/707/)

Значит, их надо различать. Все будет ясно. Будет ясно.

*ясно* в обоих случаях - предикативный член (именная часть составного именного сказуемого). В первом он выражен кратким прилагательным, а во втором - предикатом (категорией состояния, безлично-предикативным словом, предикативным словом, предикативным наречием).

Comment: Я стал врачом (стал — это глагольная часть; врачом — именная часть, предикатив).

Comment: Предикатив - эта часть именного сказуемого, а не просто безличные слова.

Comment: Оговаривать можно в некоторых случаях. При разборе такая оговорка не нужна.

Comment: Как видите, справочная служба не ошиблась!

Comment: _Серж:  Как видите, справочная служба не ошиблась!_ === Ну как же не ошиблась? Ошиблась! Её-то спрашивали про **часть речи**, а она... Она ответила, что это именная часть составного сказуемого. Как говорится, _ты ей про Фому, а она тебе про Ерёму._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В предложении *"Все будет ясно"* слово *"ясно"* - краткое прилагательное
>   или наречие?

Краткое прилагательное.

> Но приведенное предложение - двусоставное. *Все* - подлежащее, *будет
>   ясно* - сказуемое. Именная часть выражена кратким прилагательным.

Вы правы.

> Если бы было предложение *Будет ясно*, тогда *ясно* было бы
>   предикативом.

И здесь Вы правы.

> Ответ справочной службы русского языка: *Если точнее, то это
>   предикатив.*

Справочная служба ошиблась.

Comment: Слава, а что вы понимаете под словом предикатив?

Comment: Предикатив = безлично-предикативные слова = слова состояния = слова категории состояния (неглагольные слова и связные словосочетания, функционирующие как сказуемое в односоставных безличных предложениях); в двусоставных предложениях -- слова типа _рад, готов, горазд,_ а также _в самый раз, в силах, под стать._

Answer (score 2):

Грамота.ру права. Вы путаете термины. Наречие и краткое прилагательное - это части речи.  Предикатив - это член предложения, часть составного именного сказуемого, которой может быть выражен любой частью речи, в том числе и кратким прилагательном и наречием.

В приведенном вами примере часть  **ясно**- предикатив, которая выражена кратким прилагательным.

Comment: _Предикатив - это член предложения..._ === **Серж**, а откуда Вы это взяли? === ДЛЯ СПРАВКИ: в "Словаре лингвистических терминов" так: 


**предикативы** = то же, что **категория состояния;**    а вот _именная часть сказуемого_ в этом словаре всё же называется не _предикативом,_ а **предикативным членом**.

Comment: _Серж: Грамота.ру права. Вы путаете термины._ === **Серж,** здесь не **doom** запутался, а Вы: Справку-то именно о части речи ведь и спрашивали!

Comment: Слава, терминология разная. Прочитайте в Википедии. Кстати, на Грамота.ру тоже говорится, что предикатив - СИС, в ответах поищите. А Грамота.ру не ошиблась. Она просто ушла от ответа, но ответила правильно.

Comment: _Серж: А Грамота.ру не ошиблась. Она просто ушла от ответа, но ответила правильно._ === Ну да... Так же правильно, как и Вы в первой редакции своего ответа, которую кто-то умудрился признать полезной (!!!). Потому, собственно, я и встрял в эту тему...

Comment: _Серж: Кстати, на Грамота.ру тоже говорится, что предикатив - СИС, в ответах поищите._ === Найти не поможете?

Comment: Слава, поищите в ответах, кажется, там видел. Но прочитайте ответ Дума. Материал , кстати, с Википедии.

Comment: @Слава, в корпусной грамматике об этом сказано.

Answer (score 1):

О терминологии

1) Предикативность - это модальность и время. Предикативность является грамматическим значением предложения (именно предикативность отличает предложения от слов и словосочетаний).

2) Предикативность (предикативный признак) выражает сказуемое, а подлежащее называет носителя предикативного признака.

3) Всё будет ясно (краткое прилагательное в функции именной части сказуемого). Всё сказано ясно (наречие в функции обстоятельства). Было ясно (категория состояния, или ПРЕДИКАТИВНОЕ наречие, в функции именной части сказуемого).